# How to create Draggable Tableview in Iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to create a draggable tableview in iphone,i have two tableview in a view-controller,one is ordinary tableview,but i want second tableview with draggable function,i just want to drag the tableview from bottom to center of the view.I know how to drag a image in a view controller,But i need help to create a draggable tableview.Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
@interface UITouchTutorialViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
}

@end

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    img.center = location;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: no one there foe helping me ?thanks

Comment: I think you can use the same code (with minor change) to drag table !

Comment: post your code for uiimageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface UITouchTutorialViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITableView *table;
}

@end

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    table.center = location;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: it works but when the deligate is put to filesorwner it crashes.if the deligate and datasource put off it is draggable